# Regex not working for the last few letters of String

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

This is what my header looks like

```
header = "GET method P2P-DI/1.0\n" +"Host: "+ host+ "\nOS: " + OS + "\nStatus: 404"
```

I was successfully able to get method by doing this:

```
method = re.search('GET (.*?) P2P-DI/1\.0.*',header).group(1)
```

I'm trying to just retrieve the Status Code '404'. Which returns **None has no group error**

```
status = re.search('GET .*Status: ([0-9][0-9][0-9]?)',header).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
status = re.findall('Status: (.*?)$', header)[0]
```

Comment: and add index 0. cause it returns a list. re.findall('Status: (.*?)$', header)[0]

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

> The final metacharacter in this section is `'.'`
>   It matches anything except a newline character, and there’s an alternate mode (`re.DOTALL`) where it will match even a newline.

So, you can fix your code just by specifying `re.DOTALL` in the arguments:

```
status = re.search('GET .*Status: ([0-9][0-9][0-9]?)', header, re.DOTALL).group(1)
print(status) # 404
```

As an alternative to match any character, you can use any of the following constructions:

```
[\d\D] # that means 'digit char' or 'non-digit char' => 'any char'
[\w\W] # ...
[\s\S]
```

For your example it could be:
(note that `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`)

```
status = re.search('GET [\s\S]*Status: (\d\d\d?)', header).group(1)
```

Also, for the instance given in the question, it is sufficient to use only:

```
status = re.search('Status: (\d+)', header).group(1)
```